# ¿Como des comentar una linea especifica en un archivo con un comando en linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, powershell, shell-script

tengo un archivo que tiene lo siguiente:

```
              #hola como estas
              #todo es posible
              #esto es un comentario
```

con que comando quito el comentario  usando como referencia  la palabra  inicial en este caso **(todo)** para quitar el comentario yo e usado este comando **sed -i '2 s/^#//' ejemplo.sh**  pero tengo que especificar que linea es y no me sirve

```
                 #hola como estas
                 todo es posible
                 #esto es un comentario
```

Comment: Prueba esto: **`sed -i '/todo/s/^#//g' ejemplo.sh`** . ([`Fuente`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27355109/5587982))

Comment: Aunque si es sólo en caso de que empiece con la palabra *todo*, entonces debería ser: `sed -i '/todo*/s/^#//g' ejemplo.sh`.

Comment: gracias funciono!!!

Comment: Si quieres remover todos los # es `sed -i -e 's/#/ /g' ejemplo.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres remover la almohadilla de comentario de las líneas que empiecen por una palabra dada, puedes hacer esto:

```
sed -i '/todo*/s/^#//g' ejemplo.sh
```

Aquí removerá `#` de las líneas que **empiecen** con la palabra *`todo`*.

Si es para remover todos los comentarios que **contengan** la palabra *`todo`*:

```
sed -i '/todo/s/^#//g' ejemplo.sh
```

---

Fuente: [Una respuesta de Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27355109/5587982).

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacerlo es,

```
$ sed -ri 's/^(#)(todo.*)/\2/g' ejemplo.sh
```

El cual busca que inicie con el caracter `#` después del caracter núlo de inicio `^` y lo encierra en un primer grupo, luego todo lo demás que continúe con "todo" lo encierra en un segundo grupo, y luego sustituye poniendo únicamente lo del segundo grupo `\2`.

La cuestión aquí es si el comentario se va a encontrar iniciando, si no es así, se puede quitar el caracter `^` para que quede un simple `/(#)(todo.*)/`